# Deserialize classes with the same name from different assemblies

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am getting the following runtime error:

> Types 'PaymentPortal.Payments.DataObjects.Address' and 'OurWebApp.eProc.DataFormat.Entities.Address' both use the XML type name, 'Address', from namespace ''. Use XML attributes to specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type

Both classes have the same name. I need to deserialize a request containing an OurWebApp.eProc.DataFormat.Entities.Address entry.
I cannot change the name of the classes I need deserialized and the original class is from an assembly that is third-party provided.

Is there any way I can tell the (de)serializer to interpret the incoming 'Address' as a type of OurWebApp.eProc.DataFormat.Entities.Address?

Comment: Ooops- slight detail- Preferrably without decorating the incoming Address entity with a namespace.

Comment: Can you add attribute on properties referencing the `Address` class ? like `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(Namespace = "<TheAppropriateNamespace>")]`

Comment: Are both of these classes used with web services? Either on the client or on the server side.

Comment: Whoa!! Found a slight mistake.There was a using statement declaring the third party namespace in the transaction class that is to be deserialised. This means the serializer saw both Address symbols and couldn't resolve without ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you specify a namespace on your Address class?

```
[XmlType(Namespace = "http://OurWebApp.eProc.com")]
public class Address { }
```

That should prevent any collisions in the serialization.

Comment: When I tried this, my Address object upon deserialization was null. I am guessing this is because the entity in the incoming stream does not specify a matching namespace that the serializer can latch on and hence ignores it?

Comment: Do you have a namespace in the incoming XML file?

Comment: No I don't. The incoming XML has a DOCTYPE specifying a DTD but no namespace :-\

Comment: What's your code for reading the XML? Can you post a snippet and a sample XML file?

Comment: Have you tried setting the XML root of the class? [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot(Namespace = "WhatEver")]
A shot in the dark...

Comment: Since having a namespace in the incoming XML file combined with decorating the address class with an XmlRootAttribute would have worked, I will accept this as an answer. But the error in this case was resolved by removing the said 'using' statement in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the XmlType attribute on your Address class - this will tell the XML Schema to use "ReplaceWith" instead of "Address"

```
[XmlType(TypeName="ReplaceWith")]
public class Address
{
     //...etc
}
```

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This didn't work and was my first thoughts. (See my last update -comment) Thanks though.